# Issue when installing Oracle 11G in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: oracle11g, installation, ubuntu-12.04, libstdc++

I am following the instruction to install Oracle 11G in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x64) from [this web page](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits)

Oracle 11g also needs libstdc++5 in 32bits version that is not provided with Ubuntu Pangolin, So I follow these instructions:

```
mkdir /tmp/libstdc++5
cd /tmp/libstdc++5

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_i386.deb


sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo mv /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5* /usr/lib32/
```

But when executing this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I get this error:

```
dpkg: error al procesar libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 libstdc++5: 1:3.3.6-17ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with  libstdc++5:i386 1:3.3.6-17ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

How should I deal this installation problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a few ways of going about this to fix it. I am not using a pentium processor, so i did not worry about that particular package model. Some of the 11gR2 make files are for older versions of the linux kernel, so the gcc compilers are also older.

Lets think it out, Oracle Enterprise is based off Red Hat. The newest version of the kernel, 'out-the-box', on Red Hat 5 was like ~ 2.6 maybe?!. So the files are gonna use a gcc version that was relative to the kernel at the time. Red Hat, unlike its daughter project Fedora, is a fairly slow evolving creature in terms of kernel version.

I have used the libstc++5_3.3.6-25.deb packages (i386 and amd64). That particular package set (3.3.6-17) is for the i686 P6 micro-architecture. Which is the Intel Pentium class of cpu's.

I do not know what you are using 11g on, or for, but the packages I have listed will work if your CPU is not a Pentium. Ive used the enterprise manager, the database, sqlplus, and SQL Developer. I even downloaded Data Modeler and use it. But thats another 5,000 words of details on how to get that puppy running. Back to the question at hand:

1. If not already done; create the Oracle user, and the dba, oper, and oinstall groups.
2. Give the /mnt_pt/././ directory to the oracle user and oinstall group with -R privleges

~$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt_pt/app   (i.e. opt directory is used frequently or create one)
~$ sudo useradd -g oinstall -G dba   -d /mnt_pt/app  -s /bin/bash oracle
~$ sudo passwd oracle
~$ sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /mnt_pt/app

3.1 download the synaptic package manager. $ sudo apt-get install synaptic -y
3.2 download mlocate (should be installed) $ sudo apt-get install mlocate -y

4.1 Go to the User and User Groups app: SystemSettings>users and accounts. Set the oracle account type to administrator.

4.2 Log out of your account, enter the oracle account.

4.3 From the oracle account open Synaptic Package manager. Search for the libstdc++5 (3.3.6-25) files. DO NOT INSTALL THEM!!!!

4.4 Mark both packages from installation. DO NOT INSTALL THEM!!!

4.5 On the Package menu of the Synaptic app, disable the Automatically Install feature.

4.6 Open the File menu of synaptic, and select the Generate Script option and choose the directory you made as the save destination. (In your case /tmp/libstdc++5)

4.7 QUIT without apply changes.

5.1 Manually open the file you saved the script in. Right click the libstdc++5 script, and choose run in terminal.

5.2 This will deliver two .deb packages. Change your forcearch code from 3.3.6-17 to 3.3.6-25

6.1 Find out where the libraries (libstdc++.so.5) are by running the following code:
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libstdc++.so.5        .......(the .so. stands for libraries)

6.2 Your looking for 5 and 5.07. now run the following lines of code to move it where you want them (file is the parent directory where they are stored)
sudo mv /file/lib/libstdc++.so.5* /usr/lib32/

I installed Fedora 19 just to try and see where I was making errors and if I could get those packages. It was a learning experience. That particular package set is for the i686 P6 micro-architecture. Which is a hard one to find! Fedora 19 is EXTREMELY SHARP but, I set out to use Ubuntu, so that's what I did!! By the way the hardest part comes after that!

Anymore questions let me know!

P.S. if you are using a pentium I advise you to do a second install with fedora, wget the packages from the noarch repository, transfer those to a usb, switch back to Ubuntu, and after installing alien and rpm, from the command-line run the alien command for the packages via the directory they are in (or right click the packages), and then do a dpkg-forcearchitecure.